# How to do custom paging with EntitySetController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to implement custom paging with the `EntitySetController`.

```
public class MyController : EntitySetController<Poco, int>
{
    public IQueryable<Poco> Get()
    {
        var result = _myBusinessLogic.Search(QueryOptions.Top.Value);
        return result.AsQueryable()
    }
 }
```

I think I'm missing something because it looks like the controller is trying to apply paging to the results of the `Search` method that already returns just one page. How can I prevent it from doing that and apply paging myself?

It looks like I can just inherit from ODataController instead and implement:

```
public IEnumerable<Poco> Get(ODataQueryOptions odataQueryOptions)
```

but I was wondering if I can stay with `EntitySetController` so that there's less plumbing code to write.

I wanted to stick to the OData format and not return `PageResult<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only take full control of the query using ODataQueryOptions or let the framework handle it completely for you using QueryableAttribute. There is no middle ground unfortunately.

So, I think doing an ODataController is the right way to solve this now.

That said, I can suggest a dirty workaround that would work for the time being. Beware that this relies on internal implementations that might/will change and break you.

```
public class MyController : EntitySetController<Poco, int>
{
    public IQueryable<Poco> Get()
    {
        var result = _myBusinessLogic.Search(QueryOptions.Top.Value);
        RemoveQueryString(Request, "$top");
        return result.AsQueryable()
    }    

    // This method relies that code that looks for query strings uses the extension
    // method Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs that relies on cached implementation to 
    // not parse request uri again and again.
    public static void RemoveQueryString(HttpRequestMessage request, string name)
    {
        request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.RequestQueryNameValuePairsKey] = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(kvp => kvp.Key != name);
    }
}
```